# Insertion Sorting numbers

Tags: java, sorting, for-loop

```
public void sort(){

      int temp;
      int comparisons=0;
      int countSwap=0; 
      int a []  = {7,4,1,6,3,4,2};

        for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
            for(int j = i ; j > 0 ; j--){
                if(a[j] < a[j-1]){
                    temp = a[j];
                    a[j] = a[j-1];
                    a[j-1] = temp;
                    countSwap++;
                }
                comparisons++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("comparisons: "+comparisons);
        System.out.println("swaps: "+ countSwap);
}
```

I am trying to use a insertion sort and I thought this was right but the number of comparisons is wrong.  This sorts the numbers but it does more comparisons then it is supposed to.  comparisons should be 18 but it is at 21 right now.  Any hints on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: why **comparisons++** is outside the **if** statement ??

Comment: @sharif because it only swaps in the if loop.  I need to keep track of all comparisons

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
      int  temp;
      int comparisons=0;
      int countSwap=0; 
      int a []  = {7,4,1,6,3,4,2};
      int i,j;
      for( i = 0; i <7; i++) {
         for( j = i+1 ; j<7 ; j++){
              if(a[j] < a[j-1]){
                 temp = a[j];
                 a[j] = a[j-1];
                 a[j-1] = temp;
                 countSwap++;
             }         
   comparisons++;
 }
    }    
    printf("%d", comparisons);
    return 0;
}                                                                      21 is the right answer . i think so.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Did you mean [Cocktail sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_sort)? If yes, your code is not Cocktail sort. Your code is Bublesort.</strike>

Edit:

21 are right. Why it should be 18? For every itteration of first for loop you are comparing one more. So you have 6 itterations. Thats 1+2+3+4+5+6 = 21

Change your code like this and you can see it:

```
public void sort(){    
    int temp;
    int comparisons=0;
    int countSwap=0; 
    int a []  = {7,4,1,6,3,4,2};

    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        for(int j = i ; j > 0 ; j--){
            if(a[j] < a[j-1]){
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j-1];
                a[j-1] = temp;
                countSwap++;
            }

            comparisons++;
            System.out.println("Comp "+(comparisons)+": "+a[j]+" < "+a[j-1]);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("comparisons: "+comparisons);
    System.out.println("swaps: "+ countSwap);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

Comment: No I ment insertion sort